# How to pair two dataframe

Tags: python

The first datafrane is the dividendyield ratio for each stock of all trade days from 20200601 to 20201031

```
ds       code                    
20200601 000001.SZ           1.64
         000002.SZ           3.96
         000004.SZ           0.00
         000005.SZ           0.00
         000006.SZ           3.68
         000007.SZ           0.00
         000008.SZ           0.33
         000009.SZ           0.28
...                           ...
20201031 688567.SH           0.00
         688568.SH           0.00
         688569.SH           0.00
         688571.SH           0.00
         688777.SH           0.00
         688788.SH           0.00
         688981.SH           0.00

[580720 rows x 1 columns]
```

The second dataframe stands for the stock pool on each day that I actually need

```
               code
ds                 
20200601  000001.SZ
20200601  000002.SZ
20200601  000004.SZ
20200601  000008.SZ
20200601  000009.SZ
20200601  000012.SZ
...             ...
20201030  603989.SH
20201030  605199.SH
20201030  605333.SH
20201030  605388.SH
20201030  605399.SH

[204000 rows x 1 columns]
```

What I suppose to do is that, on each tradeday, selecting all the stocks in the first dataframe that also lie in the second dataframe. To be more specific, the usable stock pool for every tradeday only consists of 2000 different individual stock, but the original data (i.e. dataframe 1) includes much more individual stocks. The goal is actually to find all the usable data.
Take 20200601 as an example. My ideal result is:

```
20200601 000001.SZ           1.64
         000002.SZ           3.96
         000004.SZ           0.00
         000008.SZ           0.33
         000009.SZ           0.28
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide your expected output as well.

Comment: sure, I edited it

Comment: Can you also provide the code for how you created these ```DataFrames```? It would make it easier to reproduce and give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ds': [20200601, 20200601, 20200601, 20200601, 20200601, 
                           20200601, 20200601, 20200601],
                    'code': ['000001.SZ', '000002.SZ', '000004.SZ', '000005.SZ', 
                             '000006.SZ', '000007.SZ', '000008.SZ', '000009.SZ'],
                    'ratio': [1.64, 3.96, 0.00, 0.00, 3.68, 0.00, 0.33, 0.28]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby(['ds','code'])['ratio'].apply(sum))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ds': [20200601, 20200601, 20200601, 20200601, 20200601],
                    'code': ['000001.SZ', '000002.SZ', '000004.SZ', '000008.SZ', 
                             '000009.SZ']}).set_index('ds')

result = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), how='inner', left_on=['ds','code'], right_on=['ds','code'])
result = pd.DataFrame(result.groupby(['ds','code'])['ratio'].apply(sum))
print(result)
```